# C# WPF conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox`. I want to be able to get the first line and the last line. The code is written for Windows Forms and I want to convert it to WPF. Here is the code:

```
int firstIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
```

How can I convert the code to WPF?

Comment: What CSharpie is trying to say is we are not a code conversion service. Attempt to convert it yourself, when you get to a specific thing that you don't know how you would transform it come back here with that specific question.

Comment: I got some of it already... How can I get my `int lastLine = richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);` ?

Comment: @MellieSegarra Have you looked at the WPF textbox yet? [it has the same method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlineindexfromcharacterindex(v=vs.110).aspx) (ok, it is GetLine***Index***FromChar***acter***Index, but it is close enough that any actual research attempt would have found it)

Answer (score 3):

If you are rewriting this code for WPF, I could offer some general pointers.

First, use a pattern like MVVM. Create a C# class which is the ViewModel, that contains a C# property which will be bound to the contents of the RichText box.

Next, write XAML that shows a RichText box, and bind the contents of the box to the aforementioned C# property.

Now, when a user types into the text box, it will automatically update the bound property string in the ViewModel. You can then obtain the first and last line from this string using normal C#.

Hints:

- Ensure that the XAML binding is two way.
- Ensure that you use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, so that when the user changes the contents of the RichText box, the result is instantly pushed into the bound property string.

There is a bit of a learning curve for WPF and MVVM, but the end result is stable, snappy applications that are easy to update and modify.

If you are unsure as to some of the terminology I have used, go through a video tutorial on WPF from some company like PluralSight or Lynda. Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with either of these companies.